# Cannot make reminder in app using swift 3

Tags: ios, swift

I'm new to ios programming so I'm stuck and don't know what is wrong despite searching everywhere for a solution.

I'm trying to create an app that with one touch of a button makes 4 reminders. I first wrote this for calendar events and worked correctly but isn't working with reminder. The app does nothing at all (no crash, no reminder).

I'm using xcode 8.1 beta swift 3, another problem is I cannot set the reminder date. In tutorials they use duadate components but that was removed in swift 3.

```
let eventStore = EKEventStore()

        switch EKEventStore.authorizationStatus(for: EKEntityType.reminder) {
        case .authorized:
            self.insertEvent(eventStore, date1: date1!, date2: date12!)
            self.insertEvent(eventStore, date1: date2!, date2: date22!)
            self.insertEvent(eventStore, date1: date3!, date2: date32!)
            self.insertEvent(eventStore, date1: date4!, date2: date42!)


        case .denied: print("Access denied")
        case .notDetermined:

            eventStore.requestAccess(to: .reminder, completion: { (granted, error) -> Void in
                if granted {
                    self.insertEvent(eventStore, date1: date1!, date2: date12!)
                    self.insertEvent(eventStore, date1: date2!, date2: date22!)
                    self.insertEvent(eventStore, date1: date3!, date2: date32!)
                    self.insertEvent(eventStore, date1: date4!, date2: date42!)
                } else { print("Access denied")  }
            })

        default: print("Case Default")
        }
}


func insertEvent(_ store: EKEventStore, date1 : Date, date2 : Date) {


    let calendars = store.calendars(for: EKEntityType.event)

    for calendar in calendars {

        if calendar.title == "Calendar" {
            // Get Start and End dates
            let startDate = date1
            let endDate = date2



            let event = EKReminder(eventStore: store)
            event.title = "\(txtField.text!)"
            event.completionDate = startDate
           // event.startDate = startDate
            //event.endDate = endDate
            event.calendar = calendar
            let alarm:EKAlarm = EKAlarm(relativeOffset: -60)
            event.alarms = [alarm]



            // Save Event in Calendar
            do {
                try store.save(event, commit: true)
                lbl.text = "Events added"

            } catch {
                print("ERROR SAVING EVENT TO CAL: \(error)")
            }


            print("startDate: \(startDate) endDate: \(endDate)")
        }

}
```

Comment: What does your code do? What debugging have you done? You have not provided nearly enough information for people to help you.

Comment: its just a simple app that gets the reminder title and a date picker time mode to select time and a button that gets the text from textfield and time from the time picker and sets 4 reminders in 4 diferent days . that is my nearly entire code i just dont know why thats not working i sayed earlier for making event in calendar works good but it doesnt make reminders

Comment: i just need an example of an app adding a reminder written with swift 3

Comment: im getting this at log : "That calendar does not allow reminders to be added"

Comment: got the problem that was this line     let calendars = store.calendars(for: EKEntityType.event) should use EKEntityType.reminder